# What is the rationale behind UIBarButtonItem not inheriting from UIView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem

UIBarButtonItem inherits from UIBarItem, which is a direct descendant of NSObject.

A UIBarItem is nothing more than a special kind of UIButton, one that you can add to a Bar.

From the Apple Doc:

> Items on a bar behave in a way similar to buttons (instances of UIButton). They have a title, image, action, and target. You can also enable and disable an item on a bar.

So can anyone please explain me why are treated "specially"?

Just out of curiosity. Thanks

Comment: You'd probably need to take that one up with Apple...

Comment: @StephenDarlington: don't think they're going to answer a question on a design decision :-)

Comment: True, but no one else is going to have the definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that Apple didn't want people to use UIBarItem outside of UIToolbar or UINavigationBar. You can't add UIBarItem as a subview to any other view because it doesn't inherits from UIView. I'm just guessing so there might be some better explanation...